# Rename all columns with values in predefined list

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I feel like this should be simple but I can't find the answer.

I have over a dozen reports that contain the same fields, but the fields have slightly different names in each report - 'total_spend' appears as 'ttl_spend' / 'total_spend' / 'totl_spnd' / etc.

I am combining them into a single dataset by wrapping all of them w bind_rows. Each dataset needs XYZ things edited and fixed. For each report in the bind, after doing whatever else I need to do, I want to apply a set of standardized names to the fields, then load and bind in the next report.

I am unable to find a command that works within a tidy/dplyr chain that takes values from a list and applies them as new column names.

What I'd like to do -

```
FieldList <- c('Name', 'OrderNumber', 'OrderDate', 'ShipDate', 'OrderTotal')

bind_rows(
read_csv(pathway/file1.csv) %>%
select(CustName, OrdNum, Date, Ship, Ttl) %>%
names(FieldList),
read_csv(pathway/file2.csv) %>%
select(NameCust, Order, OrdDate, ShipDt, OrdTotal) %>%
names(FieldList)) -> my_data
```

I have tried to use names(), colnames(), variations of rename(), and tried a few things within lapply. I cannot get it to work within the chain like I have above. I have to add each dataset to R Studio, then use names, then bind them. I want to do this within a single long bind_rows command. I know I can use rename(x1=x2) but I'd have to do that 8 times per dataset, for 15 datasets.

There's gotta be a way to update all names using a predefined list within the dplyr chain.

HELP.

Comment: you could use magrittr::set_colnames()

Comment: or `|> setNames(FieldList)`

Comment: You can also pipe to the names assignment function: `%>% \`names<-\`(FieldList)`

Comment: Thank you for these comments. It *was* that simple, I just missed it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read_csv(pathway/file1.csv) %>%
   select(CustName, OrdNum, Date, Ship, Ttl) %>%
   setNames(FieldList) %>%
   bind_rows(read_csv(pathway/file2.csv) %>%
      select(NameCust, Order, OrdDate, ShipDt, OrdTotal) %>%
      setNames(FieldList)) -> my_data
```